# AutoresetEvent and Singleton issue

Tags: c#, singleton, autoresetevent

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with the following code? Ideally it should start a thread first and then  wait for the set event. Instead of that it does not start the thread and just get stuck on WaitOne().

I am curious to know what happened to the thread and why?

```
class Program
{   
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Testing t = Testing.Instance;
        Console.Read();
    }
}


class Testing
{
    private static AutoResetEvent evt = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    public static Testing Instance = new Testing();

    private Testing()
    {
        Create();
        evt.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine("out");
    }

    private void Create()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting thread");
        new Thread(Print).Start();
    }

    private void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("started");
        evt.Set();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
So far, the description provided by @BrokenGlass makes sense. but changing the code to the following code allows another thread can access the instance methods without constructor being completed.(Suggested by @NicoSchertler).

```
private static Testing _Instance;

public static Testing Instance
{
get
{
    if (_Instance == null)
        _Instance = new Testing();
    return _Instance;
}
}
```

Comment: You have not written a "singleton". I will continue getting new instances of `Testing` every call to `Instance`. That is not a singleton.

Comment: @IAbstract: `Instance` is a singleton

Comment: @BrokenGlass, sure enough - realizing the static Instance is initialized only once, but the singleton is poorly implemented here, IMO.

Comment: @IAbstract I agree but this is just a sample to focus on some other question not on an ideal singleton pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect the root cause of this behavior is that the spawned thread cannot access the `Print` method until the constructor has finished executing - but the constructor never finishes executing because it is waiting on the signal that is triggered only from the `Print` method.

Replacing the `evt.WaitOne()`  with a long `Thread.Sleep()` call confirms the same behavior - the constructor must finish running before any instance method of the object may execute from another thread.

Comment: Hm.. this makes sense. But does anyone know, why the modified singleton works (see my answer below)? The constructor isn't completed here either before calling evt.Set().

Comment: @NicoSchertler: great question, I don't know either

Comment: @BrokenGlass I tried Sleep() and your theory made sense. But after that I saw NicoSchertler and I am back to square one.

Comment: I don't know why Nico's works either. I thought it might have to do with BeforeFieldInit, but I tried it both with and without, both 2.0 and 4.0 .NET versions, and get the same result. Where is @Jon Skeet?

Comment: Ah! I do know why it works. It works because the cctor does not contain `new Testing()`. The first member access occurs at `if (_Instance == null)`. After that line, the cctor is fully executed.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the second thread is created too early. I'm not sure why, but when started before the main program starts, it will not execute.

You should use the singleton pattern in its original version. This will work.

```
private static Testing _Instance;

public static Testing Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (_Instance == null)
            _Instance = new Testing();
        return _Instance;
    }
}
```

Additionally, you should not make the evt variable static. The instance variable should be the only static member of a singleton class in most cases.

Comment: your singleton implementation is not thread-safe - might want to check here for safer approaches: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be an issue with the relative timing of the static field initialization.  Try initializing `evt` in the constructor of `Testing` instead:

```
private static AutoResetEvent evt;
public static Testing Instance = new Testing();

private Testing()
{
    evt = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    Create();
    evt.WaitOne();
    Console.WriteLine("out");
}
```

I should note this is really just a guess- I'd have thought this code would work fine.

Comment: Can you put a debugger breakpoint on the line `evt.Set();` and see if it ever gets called?

Comment: How would it get called? It isn't going to get called.

Comment: @IAbstract in `Create`, a thread is started to call `Print`: `new Thread(Print).Start();`